# executar função do .GlobalEnv em processamento paralelo

Tags: r, multithreading, paralelismo, dplyr

Preciso executar uma função que está no .GlobalEnv em um processamento paralelo utilizando o pacote multidplyr.

Utilizando um exemplo simples e sem processamento paralelo, funciona como esperado:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(multidplyr)

data.frame(x = 1:10) %>%
  mutate(y = purrr::map(x, add_a))
```

Mas quando tento colocar o paralelismo, ele não reconhece a função "add_a"

```
add_a <- function(x) {
  paste0(x, "A")
}

data.frame(x = 1:10) %>%
  partition() %>% 
  mutate(
    y = purrr::map(x, add_a)
  )
```

Retornando a seguinte mensagem:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  10 nodes produced errors; first error: objeto 'add_a' não encontrado
```

Comment: Prezado @Italo Cegatta, esse link talvez o ajude: https://github.com/hadley/multidplyr/issues/15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem que exportar o objeto `add_a` para cada nó do cluster.

Uma forma de fazer isso é criar o cluster manualmente e adicionar a função em cada nó.

Por exemplo:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(multidplyr)

add_a <- function(x) {
  paste0(x, "A")
}

cluster <- create_cluster() # cria o cluster
cluster_assign_value(cluster, "add_a", add_a) # adiciona a função add_a a cada nó

data.frame(x = 1:10) %>%
  partition(cluster = cluster) %>% # fala qual cluster você vai usar
  mutate(
    y = purrr::map(x, add_a))

Source: party_df [10 x 3]
Groups: PARTITION_ID
Shards: 7 [1--2 rows]

# S3: party_df
       x PARTITION_ID         y
   <int>        <dbl>    <list>
1      1            1 <chr [1]>
2      6            1 <chr [1]>
3      9            2 <chr [1]>
4      5            3 <chr [1]>
5      7            3 <chr [1]>
6      2            4 <chr [1]>
7      3            5 <chr [1]>
8     10            5 <chr [1]>
9      8            6 <chr [1]>
10     4            7 <chr [1]>
```